# multiprogramming on single kernel thread operating systems

Tags: operating-system

Suppose there is a system with a single processor and an operating system that has single kernel thread and I run a `C program` having `scanf() function`.

Now if I execute the program and don't supply values. **How kernel would handle this?** I mean since `scanf()` executes a blocking system call, `read()` and kernel is executing on the processor to handle the system call and is blocked. How would kernel would make another process to run which itself is blocked.

How multiprogramming is supported on single kernel thread operating system.

Answer (score 0):

A kernel doesn’t have to have a thread context for each user thread.  In particular, many microkernels have no notion of a kernel thread context at all.   These *stateless* kernels manipulate data structures representing threads, so when one wants to *read*, the kenrel might start the io and enqueues a data structure (a continuation) to record what to do when the io is complete.  Then kernel is then free to select another thread to run while the io operation is in progress.

The classic *heavyweight* thread model has become ubiquitous due to unix (later linux), but is by no means the only or even the best model.

Answer (score 0):

> How kernel would handle this? I mean since scanf() executes a blocking system call, read() and kernel is executing on the processor to handle the system call and is blocked. How would kernel would make another process to run which itself is blocked.

If the system supports "more threads than CPUs"; then it must have something (a scheduler) to figure out which thread gets to use which CPU somewhere (maybe in kernel, maybe not). In this case, hopefully (but not necessarily), if a thread blocks the scheduler will mark the thread as blocked (and why) and assign the CPU to a different thread, and then later (when it's notified that whatever the blocked thread was waiting for has occurred) the scheduler will unblock the thread and let it use a CPU again.